# Shapefile to img conversion tool

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, image

I've been looking for a tool to convert shapefiles to img files (for eventual use in a Garmin GPS device). Any idea of how to perform such conversion or of any tools that can do that?

I'm using QGIS.

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239419/uploading-shapefile-onto-garmin-gps-and-displaying-it-over-basemap help?

Comment: Can you export the Project as Image?  Project => Import/Export => Export Map to Image.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. That would be a nice and easy way to convert a project or a shp file to img format but QIS (as far as I can see with the version I have, i.e. 3.28) does not provide this option. Does anyone knows of a plugin that would allow to convert shp to img format?